# is there other styles in visual studio 2013 for my forms

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

i'm developping on vb using visual studio 2013.
in my application i'm focusing on the graphics part more than the code. I'm looking if there is any other styles that i can apply for my forms, buttons , textboxs ... other than the classic forms and textboxs ?
for example can i create some buttons like the windows 8 buttons without creating a windows store project.

Comment: Search Winforms Skinning for possible libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you work with vb and WinForms? If so, you might wanna try working with [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of WinForms. To describe it very vagualy, it allows you to define your ui by xml (like css).